# What's the significance of the letters to the left of the => in a lambda for Entity Framework Fluent API?

Tags: entity-framework

I was given the following as an example:

```
   public TestAccountConfiguration()
    {

        HasRequired(a => a.Application)
            .WithMany(t => t.TestAccounts)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ApplicationId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Is there a significance with all the letters a, t, d ? When I look at examples it seems like people just choose any character sometimes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070919/naming-convention-for-lambdas

Answer (score 1):

They're [lamdba expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).  They're local variables, and they can be anything you want.

```
HasRequired(app => app.Application)
            .WithMany(test => test.TestAccounts)
            .HasForeignKey(testAccount => testAccount.ApplicationId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Personally, I try to name them something relevant, but it's really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

> To create a lambda expression, you specify input parameters (if any) on the left side of the lambda operator =>, and you put the expression or statement block on the other side. For example, the lambda expression x => x * x specifies a parameter that’s named x and returns the value of x squared. You can assign this expression to a delegate type, as the following example shows:

In other words, the parameter list of a function is on the left, and the function itself is on the right of the `=>` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Those letters are the names of the parameters of the anonymous functions. Their names do not matter, you can use any name you like, except that it must not conflict with another variable with the same name. Particularly, event handlers often have a parameter named `e` already, that means that a lambda expression inside that event handler cannot use `e` again as a parameter name. Other than that, use whatever you like.

It's just like

```
int addOne1(int x)
{
   return x + 1;
}

int addOne2(int y)
{
   return y + 1;
}

Func<int, int> addOne3 = z => z + 1;
```

These functions all do exactly the same thing, there is (practically) no difference between them from outside the functions.